# Passing data between Tab Bar Controllers with NSNotificationCenter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, message-passing

I'm trying to pass data between tab bar controllers for the firts time, but it doesn't work. 
First Controller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var sentNotificationLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateNotificationSentLabel:", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
}

@IBAction func notify() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil, userInfo:["message":"Something"])
}

func updateNotificationSentLabel(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,String!>
    let messageString = userInfo["message"]
    sentNotificationLabel.text = messageString


}
}
```

Here it works ok, the sentNotificationLabel.text is "Something"

Second Controller is similiar, but he's not receiving any notification.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var notificationLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateLabel:", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
}

func updateLabel(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,String!>
    let messageString = userInfo["message"]
    notificationLabel.text = messageString


}
```

}

What I am doing wrong? How to change that?

Comment: Could you please describe your how you check that the notification is not being passed? Please remember that the view controller presented in the second tab will not be loaded until the user selects it.

Comment: Ok, You are right. When I first select the second tab bar and return to first controller - then it works. Can I load it before that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are sending the message before the second view controller is registered.

`NSNotificationCenter` doesn't support *sticky* notifications - in other words, the message won't be cached. If no-one is listening at the very moment the notification is sent, it's just gone.

The easiest fix is to register your `SecondViewController` for notification in initialiser. However, than the UILabel is not yet loaded - we are before `viewDidLoad` callback. The solution is to cache the received message locally and use it to set the label text when it's ready.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var notificationLabel: UILabel!
    var cachedMessage : String? = nil

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateLabel:", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let cachedMessage = cachedMessage {
            notificationLabel.text = cachedMessage
        }
    }

    func updateLabel(notification:NSNotification) {
        let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,String!>
        let messageString = userInfo["message"]
        if let notificationLabel = notificationLabel {
            notificationLabel.text = messageString
        } else {
            cachedMessage = messageString
        }
    }
}
```

Since controllers are being initialised before they are being displayed, the message should be delivered properly.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I think UILabel is nil.

Comment: @migari yes, it's `nil`. I've updated the response to reflect on that.

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to understand it, but it works great. cacheMessage is receiving message in initialiser, when UILabel doesn't exist and then passes it in viewDidLoad to UILabel?

Comment: @migari it's just as you described, so apparently you do understand it already :) Controller is registering for notifications in initialiser, than the notificatation is passed from FirstViewController to the SecondViewController, it's cached in the SecondViewController because UILabel doesn't exist yet, and after UILabel is loaded its value is set to show the cached message.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add observer in **init method**

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addBadge", name: "addBadge", object: nil)

}
```